# .NET 4.8 ASP.NET Swagger SwashBuckle Request contains an entity body but no Content-Type header. Media type application/octet-stream not supported

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, swagger, swagger-ui

Hello I have problem with configuring/testing **Swashbuckle/Swagger 5.6.0 with .NET Framework 4.8** (ASP.NET  [**not ASP.NET Core!**])

Testing GET methods from WebUI Swagger throws an error.

[image]

Doing the same with postman is:

- Content-Type: "application/json" - OK
- Content-Type: "application/ocet-stream" - same error

Response body error:

```
Message: "The request contains an entity body but no Content-Type header. The inferred media type 'application/octet-stream' is not supported for this resource.",
ExceptionMessage: "No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'SomeParams' from content with media type 'application/octet-stream'.",
ExceptionType: "System.Net.Http.UnsupportedMediaTypeException",
StackTrace: "   w System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions.ReadAsAsync[T](HttpContent content, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   w System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.FormatterParameterBinding.ReadContentAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)"
```

Looks like there's problem with missing Request Content-Type header and I am unable to set it up properly inside SwaggerWebUI.

There's no **Produces** / **Consumes** attribute in ASP.NET Swashbuckle so I added them manually (customattribute + customfilters + registration in SwaggerConfig.cs) following instructions from:
https://blog.kloud.com.au/2017/08/04/swashbuckle-pro-tips-for-aspnet-web-api-part-1/
But its not working and Parameter content type combobox doesn't appear.

I also have tried editing **WebApiConfig.cs** with/without Global/normal formatters adding/clearing SupportedMediaTTypes etc.

```
    //config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"));

    var mediaType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

    var formatter = new System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter();
    formatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Clear();
    formatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(mediaType);

    
    config.Formatters.Clear();
    config.Formatters.Add(formatter);

    var jsonFormatter = new System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter();
    jsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Clear();
    jsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"));

    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Add(jsonFormatter);

    config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"));
    config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/xml"));
```

Sample Controller code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Http;
namespace MainClass
{
    public class xxx_V1Controller : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        [SwaggerConsumes("application/json")]
        [SwaggerProduces("application/json")]
        [Route("api/xxx_V1/GetAll/", Name = "xxx_V1_GetAll")]
        public Rxxx_V1 GetAll(SomeParamsXyz)
        {
            return AuthorizationController.MainClass.yyy_GetAll_V1(SomeParams xyz);
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("api/xxx_V1/GetAll2/", Name = "xxx_V1_GetAll2")]
        public Rxxx_V1 GetAll2(SomeParams xyz)
        {
            return AuthorizationController.MainClass.yyy_GetAll2_V1(SomeParams xyz);
        }
    }
}
```

SomeParams Class

```
public class SomeParams : IXyz, IFilters
{
   public string XXX { get; set; }
   public bool GetCountOnly { get; set; }
   public bool YYY{ get; set; }
   public LoadOptions Options { get; set; }
   public List<Filter> Filters { get; set; }
}
```

http://localhost:20220/swagger/docs/v1 fragment:

```
"/api/xxx_V1/GetAll": {
    "get": {
        "tags": [
            "xxx_V1"
        ],
        "operationId": "xxx_V1_GetAll",
        "consumes": [
            "application/json"
        ],
        "produces": [
            "application/json"
        ],
        "parameters": [
            {
                "name": "options.xxx",
                "in": "query",
                "required": false,
                "type": "string"
            },
            {
                "name": "options.getCountOnly",
                "in": "query",
                "required": false,
                "type": "boolean"
            },
            {
                "name": "options.YYY",
                "in": "query",
                "required": false,
                "type": "boolean"
            },
            {
                "name": "options.options.getCountOnly",
                "in": "query",
                "required": false,
                "type": "boolean"
            },
            {
                "name": "options.options.YYY",
                "in": "query",
                "required": false,
                "type": "boolean"
            },
            {
                "name": "options.filters",
                "in": "query",
                "required": false,
                "type": "array",
                "items": {},
                "collectionFormat": "multi"
            }
        ],
        "responses": {
            "200": {
                "description": "OK",
                "schema": {
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/xxxx.Objects.Rxxx_V1"
                }
            }
        }
    }
},
```

Custom filters Consumes / Produces propably work beacuse all other Get Methods without those attribute has json with application/xml too.

```
"consumes": [
  "application/json",
  "application/xml"
],
"produces": [
  "application/json",
  "application/xml"
],
```

Comment: I don't remember but propably just used Postman

Answer (score 0):

I found a site that stated the Swashbuckler team decided to not support GET calls with a Body.  I tried all the above solutions, but none worked for me.  The solution for me was to change the action to a POST.  Sorry I don't have a link to the discussion.  But here is GitHub reporting it as Bug, but it was closed. https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/5388

Comment: Generally idea says GET shouldn't have body, but anyway its often not respected (elastic search, and mostly another custom filter criterias with GET requests)